# Remove All Methodinvocation from JAVA Source AST

Tags: java, eclipse, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

Hi i find all [Methodinvocation](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/MethodInvocation.html) with [ASTVisitor](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/ASTVisitor.html) and will remove the all with [ASTRewrite](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/rewrite/ASTRewrite.html) but when use "for loop" for remove methods, only remove first method invocation on ever call event. i guess problem reason don't refresh AST , CompiliationUnit , ICompilationUnit or [ASTRewrite](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/rewrite/ASTRewrite.html) but i don't know when and how can refresh that for remove all in first event.

```
static void createAST(ICompilationUnit unit) throws JavaModelException {
    // now create the AST for the ICompilationUnits
    CompilationUnit parse = parse(unit);
    MethodVisitor visitor = new MethodVisitor();
    parse.accept(visitor);
    for (MethodInvocation metInv : visitor.getMethods1()) {
        try {
            //if declarated by user. 
            if (metInv.resolveMethodBinding().getDeclaringClass().isFromSource()) {
                methodInvocRemove(unit, metInv);
            }
        
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("EXCEPOTION:" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

this method for remove all MethodInvocations.

```
private static void methodInvocRemove(ICompilationUnit unit, MethodInvocation met) {
    try {
        IProject project = unit.getJavaProject().getProject();
        CompilationUnit astRoot = parse(unit);
        // create a ASTRewrite
        AST ast = astRoot.getAST();
        ASTRewrite rewriter = ASTRewrite.create(met.getParent().getParent().getAST());
        rewriter.remove(met.getName().getParent(), null);
        TextEdit edits;
        edits = rewriter.rewriteAST();
        Document document = new Document(unit.getSource());
        edits.apply(document);
        // this is the code for adding statements
        unit.getBuffer().setContents(document.get());
        unit.getBuffer().close();
    } catch (MalformedTreeException e) {
        System.out.println("EXP!!!" + e.getMessage());
    } catch (BadLocationException e) {
        System.out.println("EXP!!!" + e.getMessage());
    } catch (JavaModelException e) {
        System.out.println("EXP!!!" + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        System.out.println("EXP!!!" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

this method for find method invocation with ASTVisitor. after every event on eclipse JDT call this method.

```
public static void findMethod(IProject project) {
    try {
        if (project.isNatureEnabled("org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature")) {
            IPackageFragment[] packages = JavaCore.create(project).getPackageFragments();
            for (IPackageFragment myPack : packages) {
                if (myPack.getKind() == IPackageFragmentRoot.K_SOURCE) {
                    for (ICompilationUnit unit : myPack.getCompilationUnits()) {
                        CompilationUnit parse = parse(unit);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (CoreException e) {
        System.out.println("EXP!!!"+e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

sample code of Java file for parse and modification.

```
public class MethodInvoc {

private void invoc1()
{
    MethodDeclar object1 = new MethodDeclar();
    System.out.println(object1.getStr());
}

private void invoc2() {
    MethodDeclar object2 = new MethodDeclar();
    System.out.println(object2.getStr());
}

private void invoc4()
{
    MethodDeclar object3 = new MethodDeclar();
    System.out.println(object3.getStr());
}
}
```

after call event and run methodInvocRemove above code change to:

```
 public class MethodInvoc {

private void invoc1()
{
    MethodDeclar object1 = new MethodDeclar();
    System.out.println();
}

private void invoc2() {
    MethodDeclar object2 = new MethodDeclar();
    System.out.println(object2.getStr());//not change this :( 
}

private void invoc4()
{
    MethodDeclar object3 = new MethodDeclar();
    System.out.println(object3.getStr());//not change this :( 
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to cache your `ASTRewrite` per `CompilationUnit`, remove all the `MethodInvocation` nodes with `ASTRewrite.remove(...)` and then apply all the edits only once.

So in pseudo-code:

```
ASTRewrite rewriter = ASTRewrite.create(astRoot.getAST());
for (MethodInvocation metInv : getAllMethodInvocationsToRemove()) {
    rewriter.remove(metInv, null);
}
unit.applyTextEdit(rewriter.rewriteAST(), new NullProgressMonitor());
```

To apply the edits in `rewriter`, I have had good experiences with this code (where `unit` is an instance of `ICompilationUnit`) instead of using the `Document`:

```
unit.applyTextEdit(rewriter.rewriteAST(), new NullProgressMonitor());
```

Also you might want to look at this post, and use `ICompilationUnit.becomeWorkingCopy` as well as `ICompilationUnit.commitWorkingCopy` to wrap your changes: [Eclipse AST not changing files which are not opened in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22317911/eclipse-ast-not-changing-files-which-are-not-opened-in-eclipse/22450234#22450234)